# Plantuml stopped working with new version of Java 1.7.0.21

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, uml, plantuml

PlantUML used to work properly on my machine but ever since I upgraded Java version to 1.7.0.21, it has stopped generating UML diagrams.

This is the error message I get on Eclipse SDK 4.2.1. when I have 
@startuml
testdot
@enduml

Error message: 
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments"

Any workarounds to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by replacing the new plantuml.jar version to this path

C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.sourceforge.plantuml.eclipse_1.1.8.7950\lib\plantUml

Apparently, it appears that I have been using older version of plantuml.jar file (version 7950). I have replaced with this new one to work with Java version to 1.7.0.21.

The new [plantuml](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/download.html) version is available

Comment: The above problem is related to: http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.fr/2013/04/illegalargumentexception-executable.html

Answer (score 0):

See http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/news.html
Version 7964 fixed the issue.